# Spring JPA - creating complex Many-to-Many tables with inheritance classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, spring-boot

I have a quite specific question. On my code base currently I have a few classes that inherit from a `SuperClass`, and two particular classes have a `ComplexRelationship` Many-To-Many type of relationship. This relationship may occur multiple times for the same pair `(ClassA, ClassB)` so I can't use them as a primary key.

I structured the classes as the following:

```java
@Entity(name = "SuperClass")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class SuperClass {
    //...
}


@Entity(name = "ClassA")
public class ClassA extends SuperClass {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<ClassB> manyComplexRelationships;
    //...
}


@Entity(name = "ClassB")
public class ClassB extends SuperClass {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<ClassA> manyComplexRelationships;
    //...
}


@Entity(name = "complexrelationship")
public class ComplexRelationship {
    @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    ClassA classA;
    @ManyToOne
    ClassB classB;
    // other attributes to be persisted
    //...
}
```

As you can see, `SuperClass` is defined to use a `SINGLE_TABLE` hierarchy, and I'm trying to lazily load the `ComplexRelationship` collections. However, after tons of trial and error, I found that spring is creating the relationship table like so:

```sql
create table complexrelationship_superclass
(classa_id not null, complexrelationship_id not null, classb_id not null)
create table complexrelationship (id, classa_id, classb_id, ...)
```

as you can see, the `complexrelationship_superclass` table was supposed to the the `@ManyToOne` relationship table for those classes, but it has three columns instead of the usual two - probably due to the use of `SINGLE_TABLE`.

So, my questions are

- How do I keep the `SINGLE_TABLE` hierarchy while also using this type of complex relationship?
- How do I create this type of relationship, in a way that I can take advantage of it to query by its attributes? ie. "Select all ClassB which have a flag on a ComplexRelationship whose ClassA is ?1"

Using Spring Boot v 1.5.8.RELEASE

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the SuperClass table? this class used just for common functionality?

Comment: In my opinion on the OneToMany manyComplexRelationships the mappedBy attribute is missing.

Comment: _This relationship may occur multiple times for the same pair (ClassA, ClassB) so I can't use them as a primary key._  Can you elaborate this with some data example?